# Why does checked ul not working in chrome

Tags: html, css

Got a demo here:

Choosing the "Winter" radio input should open up a submenu. Works in Firefox but not in chrome.

I can fix with javascript, but I'm trying to do html+css only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like webkit has a bug where you can't chain adjacency selectors on pseudo classes.

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu

Only known solution is to change up the order of the label and checkboxes and do some unconventional styling to align visually.

Comment: Must the `ul` be exactly two steps away from the `:checked` element? If it simply has to come after it, `:checked ~ ul` works just fine in WebKit.

Comment: Yes, it's basically the same as `+` without the immediately-following restriction.